# jQuery regex pattern match

Tags: regex

I'm trying to validate what my users enter in a field.

The pattern is `????-????-????-????-????-????` where `?` can be a-zA-Z0-9

I'm trying to work out what regex is needed to confirm the user has entered a valid matching pattern. I've spent some time googling but I've not found anything similar.

So far I've got to `/^([a-z0-9]{4}-){5}/i` but that doesn't work.

Anyone suggest how to do this?

Comment: Please see [ask], then revise your post title to ask a clear, specific question. Don't add tags.

Comment: Use a basic regex debugger, it should be pretty clear where you're falling short: https://regex101.com/r/FSL78s/1

Comment: Extend it to match the missing part and add an achor `^[a-z0-9]{4}(?:-[a-z0-9]{4}){5}$` https://regex101.com/r/wwAUgo/1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure what *jQuery* has to do with the specific issue. In jQuery you get an INPUT's value using `$instance.val()`, in JavaScript using `Element.value`, then the JavaScript's [RegExp.prototype.test()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/test) is available in both to **test** the string validity.

The **issue** in your code is in that you expect a dash `-` even after the sixth set of *a-z0-9* characters. Instead, what you need is one group of four `[a-z0-9]` chars, and five groups of *dash-prefixed* `-[a-z0-9]`, or expressed in JavaScript Regexp notation as:

```
/^[a-z0-9]{4}(?:-[a-z0-9]{4}){5}$/i
```

then, to test your INPUT value you might use:

```js
const elCode = document.querySelector(`[name="product-code"]`);
const code = elCode.value;
const isValid = /^[a-z0-9]{4}(?:-[a-z0-9]{4}){5}$/i.test(code);
console.log(isValid); // true|false
```

A similar regular expression could be also used in the required INPUT's `pattern` attribute but you need to take care for the insensitive characters literally (since the `i` flag is not yet available):

```css
input:focus:invalid:not(:placeholder-shown) {
  color: hsl(0 70% 50%);
}
```

```html
<form action="">
  <input
    name="product-code"
    type="text"
    required
    pattern="^[a-zA-Z0-9]{4}(-[a-zA-Z0-9]{4}){5}$"
    placeholder="Product code"
  >
  <button>Validate</button>
</form>
```

The above are means to stop prematurely Form submit due to user mistakes, but no-one can stop a bad actor to simply remove those HTML attributes from your INPUT element and submit the form anyway; so make always sure to validate submitted values on the server-side of your application.